# How does the Sankt Goar isogloss work?

Tags: phonetics, pronunciation, german, dialects

The Sankt Goar line crosses the german town of Sankt Goar and separates the dialects that have *t* in words like *wat* and *dat* and the dialects that have *s* in the corresponding words *was* and *das*. Is this change abrupt? Does the consonant literally change from one side of the line to the other,does it happen gradually through slightly different pronunciations or do the dialects that are spoken near the line use both forms,slowly fading into just one of them the further away they are from the isogloss?

Comment: It's not purely geographic, also social.  These maps are theory, ie it could be true for the dialects but in the North/cities/elite many people do not all speak dialect, or do not speak it in all situations.  There are millions if not tens of millions of people who have say *wat/dat*, the vast majority of whom also say *was/das* in some situations.  There are similar shibboleths in English (eg *ain't*).

Comment: *wat/was* is kind of an identity marker, so more than other words many people use *wat* who say *Wasser*, not *Water* or other Low German forms.  There are many symbolic remnants of earlier dialect/language like that, eg *Moin*.

Comment: There are however isoglosses that are sharp, but more so only at some points along the line.  (Think of it like a slope.) Usually it represents limited contact, possibly a historic border, solidified with sectarian splintering.

Comment: The St. Goar line is actually fairly sharp through the villages, but it is a short segment of the very long dat-das line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good question!

Isoglosses are generally drawn as these nice, hard-edged lines on a map. On one side of the Sankt Goar line, you have *das*, and on the other side, you have *dat*.

The problem is, nothing in linguistics is ever this clear-cut. Even the boundaries between languages are fuzzy: [you can walk from Rome to Lisbon without ever crossing a hard line between two languages](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/29921/10559).

So isoglosses are a sort of "good enough" approximation. *In general*, someone on this side is more likely to use *das*, and someone on that side is more likely to use *dat*. But if you went to Sankt Goar itself, you wouldn't find half the people using *das* and half of them using *dat*: more likely, the people near the line use both versions, maybe interchangeably, maybe in a sort of diglossia (using *das* in some registers and *dat* in others). And as you get further away from the line, the probability that you'll hear one instead of the other increases.

Comment: Your answer was perfect,short and straight to the point!Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this particular change is aprupt. There are no intermediate forms between *wat* and *was* (like *wats) nor *dat* and *das*. There may be places where you can find speakers who you either form, maybe separated by age. After all, at least in Saarland *Rheinfänkisch* (the dialect with *was* and *das*) is spreading into formerly *Moselfränkisch* (the dialect with *wat* and *dat*) territory.